# Cannot ping my laptop with OS X

Tags: macos-high-sierra

There is a problem with ping within the same network on macOS High Sierra. Laptop invisible and doesn’t answer (100% packets lost). Please note it is not a router issue since also checked directly via cable.

**I’ve tried the following**:

- Turned Firewall off
- Carried out corresponding system maintenances by CleanMyMac
- Disabled all the third-party software (launch agents / daemons) from
  startup
- Reinstalled macOS
- Tried [something](http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/13/fix-wifi-macos-high-sierra-issues/) irrelevant but anyway

Unfortunately nothing helped :(

Worth mentioning, when boot from safe mode ping works fine & Mac visible to the network.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After years, when OS X updated to a newer version the problem had resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the network is working fine.

If you've just plugged the cable (Crossover) between the systems, I don't think this will work. Back in time we needed straight cables. Today I know there are network cards that are able to detect and switch the mode, but I don't trust them.

Ping sends ICMP packets not TCP/IP. So the Network over TCP or UDP can work great, but ICMP will be filtered (often called something like 'Stealth mode' or 'invisible').

I've got no OSX here. So the following part is out of my mind and a little google.

1. If you are using TCPDump on the destination, you are able to see if the ICMP Packet is delivered but dropped or if the Packet is filtered before. (Use Promiscuous mode!)
   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202013
2. Traceroute is using also ICMP, but resolve every hop on the way.
   First try to 'traceroute stackoverflow.com' to see the first hop. If the first hop isn't shown with data, we can assume the router is dropping ICMP.
   Than traceroute the IP of your destination system.
   https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25356?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US
3. Take a look at 'arp -a', if the destination system is already shown. If not, try to reach it with any service before. Maybe you see the IPv6 address instead of the IPv4. This could be an useful information.
4. Do you know the tool 'nmap'?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you LupusE.

I figured out that OS X doesn't generate ICMP replies.

**TCPDump**:

```
16:58:59.014915 48:4b:aa:c3:21:07 > dc:a9:04:6e:7f:5f, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16053, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
192.168.2.104 > 192.168.2.102: ICMP echo request, id 11772, seq 1, length 64
16:59:00.038830 48:4b:aa:c3:21:07 > dc:a9:04:6e:7f:5f, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10287, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
192.168.2.104 > 192.168.2.102: ICMP echo request, id 11772, seq 2, length 64
...
```

In addition destination host (192.168.2.102) is missing by `arp -a` from 192.168.2.104.

Will post if I ever get a solution

Thanks